# Do pip packages differ for different Operating System?

Tags: python, pip

I use pip installed the `uwsgi` package in my local repository project virtualenv (MacBook Pro).

and I use the

```
$ ./uwsgi --version
2.0.17
```

in the local repo `venv/bin`. it will shows its version.

then I use git push the local repo to the remote repo(CentOS-7.2).

now, I activate the remote_repo's `venv`, and cd to the `venv/bin`, use:

```
./uwsgi --version
```

there comes error:

```
# ./uwsgi --version 
-bash: ./uwsgi: cannot execute binaries
```

So, is the `uwsgi` package different in the different operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package contains C or other compiled language code - yes. This is why wheels have long complicated names detailing the OS and other variables.

Make setting up a venv part of your deployment. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Do the packages only differ if they contain compiled code? (I noticed it for numpy which has Fortran code / C code)

Comment: Most probably yes, that should be the signifier of differences. Of course there is also python major versions and this kind of stuff, but pure python code should pretty much be the same.